# Named SQL Server that connection stopped to run if named connection

Tags: sql-server-express

I installed a named SQL Server Express edition engine, with `SQLEXPRESS` as its instance name, some months ago. An application used to connect to that engine with a named connection. Last week it stopped to work. The named connection (`servername=ip\SQLEXPRESS`) is no longer visible on network, even though it works fine locally. Connecting from the network works fine using an anonymous connection and a static port (`servername=ip;port=portNr`). Why?